# Reading magento 1.9x htaccess file

Tags: magento-1.9

I've downloaded and installed Magento 1.9.x together with sample data on my Mac.

I've added an entry to my hosts file as follows:

```
127.0.0.1    local.magento.test
```

And in httpd-vhosts.conf I have the path to the web root set:

```
DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/Documents/vhosts/magento.test/httpdocs"
ServerName local.magento.test
```

I'm getting a 403 saying

> Server unable to read htaccess file, denying access to be safe

If I look in the apache error log it seems that it is trying to read the .htaccess file from the magento.test directory, not httpdocs

```
Permission denied: ... /Library/WebServer/Documents/vhosts/magento.test/.htaccess
```

Any ideas or suggestions much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

OK, problem solved.  I needed to add the following to my virtual hosts entry:

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```